# String representation of typed literals

Tags: jena

I am using Jena 2.6.4.

The following code

```
String v = "Parnell Square East";
Literal l = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel().createTypedLiteral(
    v, XSDDatatype.XSDstring);
System.out.println(l.toString());
```

Produces the following output:

> Parnell Square East^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string

which looks wrong to me: I would have expected:

> "Parnell Square East"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string

From a quick look at the source code of [`LiteralImpl.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/jena/2.6.4/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/impl/LiteralImpl.java#LiteralImpl.toString%28%29) I see:

```
@Override public String toString() {
    return asNode().toString( PrefixMapping.Standard, false );
}
```

Why is the second parameter (quoting) set to `false`?

If I do

```
String v = "Parnell Square East";
Literal l = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel().createTypedLiteral(v,
        XSDDatatype.XSDstring);
System.out.println(l.asNode().toString(PrefixMapping.Standard, true));
```

I get the desired output

> "Parnell Square East"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string

I just wonder why this is not the default behaviour?

Thanks,
marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee, implicit or explicit, that `toString` on any Jena node produces output that fits any particular serialization (e.g. Turtle). You might just as well ask why `toString` does not produce an XML node, or why the datatype is not abbreviated to a q-name. The view that Jena takes is that `toString` produces enough information to be useful in debugging. Any requirements beyond that are application responsibilities.

So saying, if you have a good use case feel free to submit a patch to the [Jena Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/jena). Bear in mind though, that existing user code may have come to rely on the current behaviour, so switching would have some cost so you would need to make a strong case for change!